# What does it mean when 連体形 is directly followed by は?

Tags: particles, particle-は, auxiliary-き, attributive, 連体形

Here are two lines of the lyrics in a specific song:

> [出]{で}[逢]{あ}い**しは**　[運命]{さだめ}か

and

> [纏]{まと}い**しは**　[緋]{ひ}[色]{いろ}の[棘]{とげ}の[鎧]{よろい}

I'm 99% sure that the し here is the 連体形 of き; it follows the 連用形 of [出]{で}[逢]{あ}う and [纏]{まと}う.

However, what I don't understand is why the 連体形 is being used and what it means for は to directly follow the 連体形 of a (auxiliary) verb. It would still make sense if the し was removed from both lines - is the し only there for emphasis on the fact that it happened in the past, or does it have some sort of other nuance or meaning or grammatical construction that I don't know of?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think the implication is that there is a noun that's implied. Something like 物、時、事, etc

Comment: Also related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/54540/5010 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/36095/5010 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/6714/5010

Comment: @naruto: Yes, these answer my question perfectly. Thank you!