# Dummy noun, to add or not to add

Tags: particle-の, particle-こと

Most of the time (?) a following dummy noun is required when the speaker wants to put a 用言 where a 体言 is expected, as shown by the sentence below:

> できない**の**をできないというのに、不思議があるもんか。

However, it seems that sometimes a 用言 on its own can function as a 体言, namely, with no dummy noun added, such as:

> わかるまで**待ってる**がいい。

> できそうもない幾何の問題を持って**迫った**には冷や汗を流した。

So the question boils down to:

When a 用言 is used as a 体言, in what case is the addition of a dummy noun 1) required, 2) optional, 3) plainly wrong?

All three instances are from the novel [Botchan](https://www.aozora.gr.jp/cards/000148/files/752_14964.html).

Comment: I think this link may be relevant for one of your examples (close to the bottom of the answer): https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/36739/7944

Comment: A 用言 used as a 体言 is a type of [準体言](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E6%BA%96%E4%BD%93%E8%A8%80/), and such conversion in function is called 準体法.  Apparently 準体法 was much more common in the past and now is on the way out, but we still have a lot of holdovers.
There were also の and other dummy nouns for nominalization coexisting with 準体法, and they have extended their distribution to fill the increasing gap left by it, according to [this abstract](http://www.ls-japan.org/modules/documents/index.php?content_id=823) on 日本言語学会.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The attributive form of a verb worked as a nominalized verb in archaic Japanese.

- [How can （の）目指すは be grammatical?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/12538/5010)
- [に越したことはない Wondering about the に](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/36095/5010)

In particular, `Verb + が + いい/よい` is a highly old-fashioned and pompous way of making a request/command. It's mainly used as role language of pompous nobles today.

- [<動詞の辞書形>　+　がよい ―　How is this allowed?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/6714/5010)
- [Plain Verb followed by がよい](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/64661/5010)

<sup>(待ってるがいい sounds a little unnatural today, though. 待ってる is a fairly colloquial contraction of 待っている, and がいい doesn't go well with such a colloquial expression. 待つがいい, 待っているがいい or 待っておるがよい would be more natural.)</sup>

However, this type of nominalization works only in fixed idioms, proverbs and set phrases in modern Japanese. This sentence:

> できそうもない幾何の問題を持って迫ったには冷や汗を流した

...is regarded simply as grammatically incorrect by today's standard. You simply need の after 迫った. Since this is from an old and famous novel, I imagine something like this may have been more tolerated in those days, but you should not do this in modern standard Japanese.